# Backup for GKE does not restore all volumes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, backup

I have manually triggered update of worker node pool in GKE but after update one of our database persisent volumes was recreated instead of just reattaching to pod on new node.

We have backup for GKE enabled so I tried to restore affected namespace but unfortunately volume is not created. As this is postgresql statefulset it just creates new PVC with no data. There are 2 volumes in this namespace one for application and one for database. The application volume is restored without problem but database volume does not seems to be restored at all. I have checked backups and they are successful.

```
$ gcloud beta container backup-restore volume-backups describe vb-5a2ffd18-e2e4-4a5b-86c0-cb17faa5b43e
--backup-plan=prod-cluster-backup --project=**** --location=europe-central2 --backup=sched-2023-0418-0500  
completeTime: '2023-04-18T05:01:35.748678557Z'  
createTime: '2023-04-18T05:00:13.587381260Z' 
diskSizeBytes: '17179869184' 
etag: '7' 
format: GCE_PERSISTENT_DISK 
name: projects/****/locations/europe-central2/backupPlans/prod-cluster-backup/backups/sched-2023-0418-0500/volumeBackups/vb-5a2ffd18-e2e4-4a5b-86c0-cb17faa5b43e 
sourcePvc:  
 name: data-postgresql-0   
 namespace: namespace 
state: SUCCEEDED 
storageBytes: '91448000' 
updateTime: '2023-05-01T05:00:33.812316627Z' 
volumeBackupHandle: projects/****/global/snapshots/snap-c52f0f30-d3e5-4790-84d5-90da7def8629
```

Also restore process is showed as successful but shows only application volume to be restored not database.
Whats also interesting is that application volume is created from backup with storage class refering to gkebackup but database is not.

```
data-postgresql-0                  Bound    pvc-9dcfd2c8-58aa-410b-8b03-46bd232baed6   16Gi       RWO            standard-rwo          27s
data-application                   Bound    pvc-65883a2b94bf4b44                       10Gi       RWO            gce-pd-gkebackup-ie   29s
```

I have already tried to do restore from all backups I have but result is the same. I tried to restore backup to completely new cluster but postgresql pvc is not restored.

Has anyone faced similar issue ? First of all I do not understand how this volume could be recreated during the update instead of just reattached to new node/pod.

Thank you very much